# Only wear one hat at a time?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, winter-bash-2016

When I click “wear hat” it shows that one only. I can only wear one at a time.  The position controls are applying to all hats, not just the selected one, too.

Comment: How is this supposed to be a bug? Can you post some screenshots to clarify?

Comment: How is it a bug? In previous years one could arrange multiple hats in artisic ways.  Screenshot: just see my icon now—only one hat shows.

Comment: You've always only been able to wear one hat at a time

Comment: No, last two years people have made funny tableus with them.

Comment: My avatar has 3 hats, but I'm only wearing one. The rest are screenshots of my avatar wearing the hat.

Comment: I think certain questions and answers merit an automatic 'fanatic' badge and at least 100 points of rep.

Comment: @JDługosz If you want to wear multiple hats, you need to wear a hat take a screenshot change your avatar to the screenshot, then wear a different hat. We've never had the ability to wear more than one hat at a time.

Comment: Also: [Can I wear two hat simultaneously?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/213909/195817)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**This is not a bug.**

That is how it is supposed to be, and that's also how it always was.

If you really desperately want to wear multiple hats, crop the hats using some sort of screen cropping tool, apply them to your avatar using an image editing tool (i.e. Paint), and replace your current avatar with the modified one.

Answer (score 6):

The only way to wear multiple hats, is to make a screenshot of your avatar with hat A, upload that as a new avatar, and wear hat B. You cannot wear multiple hats, it has always been this way.